# Dropwizard Custom Exception for InvalidEntityException

Tags: dropwizard

I am trying to create a customer mapper for [dropwizard validation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#validation). We are using dropwizard 0.7.0.

I am trying to extend `InvalidEntityException` which is thrown when validation error occurs. But in 0.7.0, i do not see it been supported. Wondering if anyone know what exception is thrown when validation error occurs in the the latest version of dropwizard.

Comment: FYI: Modify this example. Perhaps this can help -> http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/

Answer (score 0):

The new exception to look at is ConstraintViolationException. Also in the new version you don have have to clear out Dropwizard default InvalidEntityExceptionMapper. The post which explais this is http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fthoughtspark.org%2F2013%2F02%2F25%2Fdropwizard-and-jersey-exceptionmappers%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFU1Z9WzFzQfRG9h-sQ8C50y6sKAw